# Xcodes UITesting SwipeUp() not working since iOS 10.3

Tags: xcode, ui-automation, xcode-ui-testing, ios10.3

Since upgrading to iOS 10.3 I have noticed the swipeUp() function only swipes the table view by a very small amount.  where 1 swipeUp() call used to be more than enough, now I have 10 calls to do the same.

Has anyone got a fix for this?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

So it looks like a good way round this is to use XCUIElement's press(forDuration: thenDragTo:) method.

e.g. to scroll a tableview

```
XCUIApplication().tables.cells.element(boundBy:2).press(forDuration: 1, thenDragTo: XCUIApplication().staticTexts["My Page Header Text"])
```